# How can tenses be fused together in complex sentences with the verb "to notice" (or the like) in the main clause?

Tags: tense

I am looking at the text that I had written some time ago and I suddenly get on to the fact that the text has been edited by Mr.X. I've got a few possible ways to put across the idea that I've just gotten to know him having corrected my text, using the verb "to notice" (or the like):

1. I have just noticed that Mr.X has edited my text.
2. I have just noticed that Mr.X edited my text.
3. I just noticed that Mr.X has edited my text.
4. I just noticed that Mr.X edited my text.

All of them seem relevant for bringing in that same idea. But I can be mislead and there may be some differences which I am not grasping.

Can these four variants be used interchangeably? If not, what are the differences between them? (what tinges of meaning could they convey?)

Comment: Older speakers of British English like me would use the present perfect for recent events, so I would use (1) unless I knew when the editing took place (_Mr. X edited my text last week_).  The use of the simple past tense, which I think of as typically American, is now widespread in Britain too.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you for having heeded my question. The unwarranted simplification of language means takes away its expressive capability, thus detracting from its "lavishness and lusciousness" (if I may say so). In your trustworthy oppinion, which of the patterns from the list that have been put up at №2 and №3 (with mixed tenses) would be preferable and correct?

Comment: I've told you which I would use. Other contributors to this forum will tell you that it's fine to use the past tense.